# In Source Safe is there a way to protect crucial files being modified by some developers

Tags: version-control, visual-sourcesafe

I'd sooner not just permanently have a bunch of files checked out to me, but I'd like a way to prevent some really critical files being changed without my being aware of it.

PS Yes I know SourceSafe is terrible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only set access rights on a project by project basis.

This is done by running the the Source Safe Administration application and then go to Tools > Rights By Project. Select the required project and then give a users the required priveledges.
In order to protect a subset of files place them in a seperate project and hence protect the subset.

When you go into Source Safe if you set the working folder of the sub folder to be the same as the parent then when you do a get latest etc. all the files will be in the same folder. If you want the protected files to be in a seperate folder then set the working folder accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've had to use Source Safe but I don't think it has this kind of functionality built it.

Can you set up a separate repository/instance that excludes the users who shouldn't be allowed to modify them?

Or failing that, just keep the files always checked out on your machine :P

Answer (score 0):

check them out locked exclusive

Comment: He explicitly mentioned not wanting to keep a bunch of stuff checked out, but I didn't downvote because he may have edited in response to your post or because he could create a different account to do the checkout.

Comment: [@Joel Coehoorn]: oops, missed that - but it is really the only solution for VSS unless you partition the project